# Get reference to Java Enum that implements an interface from enum class name

Tags: java

I want to implement a basic state machine using enums; the enums implement an interface to manage allowed state transitions. But I want to configure in a property file a list of class names of enums that implement the interface and should be used in a particular context. The context is determined at runtime, and that context key maps to a property key in the properties file. Once I get the class name of the enum for a context from the properties file, how can I use that class name to get an instance reference to use that enum via the interface methods? I can see that you can use reflection to discover a particular enum's attributes but that's it. Any ideas?

Comment: if you only have the class name, you will need to use reflection... check this SO about using reflection with enum http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140537/how-to-use-java-reflection-when-the-enum-type-is-a-class

Comment: Using enum class names defeats the purpose of using enums. Enums power comes from referring to the instance names in code. Please show a pseudo line of code for how you want to use the classname, even if it doesn't compile, so we understand what your intention is.

Comment: I was using the enum as a mini state machine. Enum implements an interface which had a method getNextAllowedStates which returned a set Enum constants of the same type. But my app has the concept of a service and depending which service the request cam from I want a different state machine implementation as the state transitions are different per service. I wanted to just do something like - request is service x get enum type y or when service s get enum type t. This would be done from a factory the client would call then use interface type to get next possible states

Answer (score 1):

You're right about using reflection:

1. Use [`Class.forName`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29) to get the proper `Class` object once you've read the class name from your properties file.  Make sure you pass in the fully qualified class name.  You'll need to catch various checked exceptions here.
2. Make sure it's an enum that implements your interface, with the `isEnum` method and using the `isAssignableFrom` method from your interface's `Class` object.

   isEnum() && YourInterface.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz)
3. Use the static [`Enum.valueOf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String%29) method to get the actual enum constant from a `String` and cast it to your interface.

   ```
   (YourInterface) Enum.valueOf(clazz, stringName)
   ```

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this... it may help you:

```
public class MyTests {

  static enum XX implements Runnable {
    A, B;
    public void run() {
      System.out.println( "I'm enum value: " + this.name() );
    }
  }

  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
    new MyTests();
  }

  public MyTests() throws Exception {
    Class<?> loaded = Class.forName("MyTests$XX");
    Class<? extends Runnable> xx = loaded.asSubclass(Runnable.class);
    Runnable[] enumConstants = xx.getEnumConstants();
    for ( Runnable runnable : enumConstants ) {
      runnable.run();
    }
  }

}
```

This will print:

```
I'm enum value: A
I'm enum value: B
```

Comment: Took the liberty of replacing the unsafe cast (effectively a no-op) with an `asSubclass()` call that does ensure the correct type.

Comment: Wouldn't you get an Exception in either case should "loaded" be not of the right parameterized type? Also, you forgot to remove the casting code :)

Comment: Oops, sorry about that. Yes, you'll get a ClassCastException the way you had it, but it will be later, in a different location, where no cast exists in code. In a different context, these unsafe casts could raise mysterious `ClassCastException` errors in some far distant and unrelated code. The sole point of generics is to provide static type safety guarantees. But if you ignore warnings, the warranty is void.

Answer (score -1):

Yeah.

Don't softcode that stuff, unless you really really really need to.

http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Soft_Coding.aspx